# HTML5 Offline Application with Basic Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, basic-authentication, html5-appcache

I'm trying to get a Rails 3 project working offline using HTML5 Appcache and Rack::Offline. I am using Rails 3 Asset Pipeline which provides the added luxury of digests (application-dfla33q23jad.js) to keep the manifest files fresh. Theoretically, anytime an asset changes, the manifest will also change to include the new digested versions of the assets.

(application.manifest)

```
CACHE MANIFEST
assets/application-785189fec63978372c177135a521e081.js
assets/application-c69de8169df1ae42a1a4dcafdc5a1af4.css
assets/application.css
assets/application.js
```

The new manifest is detected by the browser, and the new assets are cached in the background, but the html does not get updated to reflect the updated assets. It's almost as though all the assets get cached except for the master entry. Notice below how the js and css links do not have the same digest as the new version resulting in a 404 (Not Found) when refreshed.

(index.html)

```
<html manifest="/application.manifest">
<head>
  <title>Project</title>
  <link href="/assets/application-cb58254cec63978372c177135a521e081.js" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/application-918b26fdf1ae42a1a4dcafdc5a1af4.css" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p> Content </p>
</body>
</html>
```

My first thought to fix this was to add the html explicitly to the manifest so the html gets updated with the rest of the assets.

```
CACHE MANIFEST
index.html
assets/application-785189fec63978372c177135a521e081.js
assets/application-c69de8169df1ae42a1a4dcafdc5a1af4.css
assets/application.css
assets/application.js
```

I believe this would have worked but index.html is protected using basic authentication so a 401 (Unauthorized) error is thrown when trying to update the appcache. Which leads me to my questions:

1. Shouldn't the appcache update the master entry (index.html) anytime the explicit entries get updated?
2. Does the appcache provide a way to include entries that are protected using basic authentication?
3. Shouldn't the appcache request use the same credentials the user entered to view the page in the first place?